# how to pass additional argument to php file in autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, autocomplete

i just want to pass arguments to php in autocomplete.code is following

```
$(function(){
        $( "#txt_supplier_account_name" ).autocomplete(
        {
           source:'./modules/stock/ajax/ajax.commonsearch.php',
           select: function(event, ui) {
        }
   })
});
```

Comment: You could add them in the querystring of the source URL.

Comment: Use query string `key` and `value` . ex: `source:'./modules/stock/ajax/ajax.commonsearch.php?key1=value1&key2=value2'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$( "#txt_supplier_account_name" ).autocomplete(
    {
       source:'./modules/stock/ajax/ajax.commonsearch.php?key1=value1&key2=value2',
       select: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Through the `source` url you can send like

```
$( "#txt_supplier_account_name" ).autocomplete(
    {
       source:'./modules/stock/ajax/ajax.commonsearch.php?key1='+value1+'&key2='+value2,
       select: function(event, ui) {
    }
});
```

And in the `ajax.commonsearch.php` you can `GET` then through the url.